# Using sort with alphanumeric filenames

Tags: sort

I'm sorting the results of a `find` command which finds all of the files in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.flac" | sort
```

What I'm expecting is a list like this:

```
./Track 1.flac
./Track 2.flac
./Track 3.flac
...
./Track 9.flac
./Track 10.flac
./Track 11.flac
```

What I'm getting is a list like this:

```
./Track 10.flac
./Track 11.flac
./Track 1.flac
./Track 2.flac
./Track 3.flac
...
./Track 9.flac
```

Is there an option to `sort` which will put them in alphanumeric ascending order so that numbers are evaluated properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to pass the `-n` and `-k2` command line options to `sort`. I.e.,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.flac" | sort -n -k2
```

When I put your unsorted filenames into  file 'data.txt' and run this command:

```
sort -k2 -n data.txt
```

I get this as output:

```
./Track 1.flac
./Track 2.flac
./Track 3.flac
./Track 9.flac
./Track 10.flac
./Track 11.flac
```

explanation of options:

```
-n (numeric sort) compare according to string numerical value
-k2 means sort on the 2nd field (and to the end of the line), 
    you could just restrict it to the second field with -k2,2
```

You didn't ask about this, and I didn't use it above, but it may come in handy some day.

```
-r reverse sort order
```

[man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) for `sort`

See my related post on SO about sorting according to different fields [Sort by third column leaving first and second column intact (in linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006431/sort-by-third-column-leaving-first-and-second-column-intact-in-linux/11006690#11006690) which explains more about the sort command.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh, use the `n` [globbing qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
print -l *.flag(n)
```